# sed Regex for capturing a digit in group

Tags: regex

Input:

```
"//*[@id='headeritems1']": {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "value": "",
          "selectorType": "xpath"
        },

            "//*[@id='headeritems3']": {

          "type": "exitPopUp",
          "value": "",
          "selectorType": "xpath"
```

Desired output:

```
"(//*[@id='headeritems1'])[2]": {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "value": "",
          "selectorType": "xpath"
        },
        "(//*[@id='headeritems3'])[2]": {
          "type": "exitPopUp",
          "value": "",
          "selectorType": "xpath"
```

How can I capture the digit headeritems 1 and 3 in group and not to replace it.

Regex I used:

```
sed -i "s/\/\/\*\[@id='headeritems[(\d)]'\]/\"(\/\/\*\[@id='headeritems\1'\])\[2\]/g"
```

Comment: Hello Sonal, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, can you use \`backticks\` to format something as `code`? For multiline pieces of code, you can also use four spaces for each line. Either way, just highlight the code in the question editor and click the button with brackets like this: {}. Thanks!

Comment: To parse a json file, sed is the wrong tool, instead use jq.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your input against this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/8sc6ST/1). Check out and let me know if this is your expected output.